# Get a list of videos from a specific channel via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to retrieve a list of videos from a specific channel via JS.

I created a project in the Developer Console and added the youtube API v3 as well as a API key.

But I can't find a rest call to get a list of videos for a channel. This documentation is driving me crazy.

How can I achieve this in the client?

Comment: what is "The Developer Console" in this instance? .. in your browser?

Comment: I've not done this but [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests) it says you use the `channels` query to get the channel info including the id of the uploads playlist, and then use the `playlistitems` query to get the videos in the uploads playlist.

Comment: The google developers console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of it to get your own uploaded videos:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/my_uploads.js

The only change you'd have to do is instead of using `mine=true` at line 14,

use `id=CHANNEL_ID`